# Which church/denomination do most writers of GotQuestions, Creation Ministries International and Answers in Genesis belong to?

Tags: denomination-survey, young-earth-creation, internet

The sites [Got Questions](https://www.gotquestions.org/) and [Creation Ministries International](https://creation.com/) and [Answers in Genesis](https://answersingenesis.org/answers/) don't really tell which churches/denominations its writers are part of. The only thing that's obvious is they're Protestants. I always wondered who their posters are. Presbyterians? Southern Baptists? Missouri Synod Lutherans?

Comment: I can tell you that one of their scientists is actually Seventh Day Adventist. They are from a range of denominations mostly evangelical. The ministry is about YECism and not denominational.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kris has given you an excellent answer (+1) but I want to add to the information about Got Questions because I have been a writer for them since 2012.

***According to their mission statement, they are Christian, Protestant, evangelical, theologically conservative, and non-denominational.***

Source: https://www.gotquestions.org/faith.html

Since this declaration is clear and unambiguous, then it’s obvious they are not going to support Catholic teachings such as Mariology, transubstantiation, the baptism of infants and apostolic succession.  Recently, I’ve had occasion to remind people who ask about Catholicism that we are a Protestant ministry.  Whenever we are asked about the theology of the Catholic Church, or even the theology of non-Trinitarian denominations, our answers are always based on the Bible.  Our purpose is to point people to God’s word and to Christ Jesus as the only way to salvation.

Their writers come from all over the world, and they are chosen because of their Protestant views and their ability to communicate Christian beliefs in a caring and sensitive manner, always using the Bible to support what is said.  Nobody at Got Questions keeps a register of whether a writer belongs to a particular denomination, or not.

For what it’s worth, I was baptised 25 years ago (as an adult) in a U.K. Baptist church.  That does not make me a Baptist.  That makes me a born-again Christian, a person who belongs to Christ Jesus.

With regard to your comment to Kris that Got Questions “tries to teach people things that are incompatible with Catholic doctrine” and that some Christians might “fall for their heresies”, all that can be said is if anybody wants to find out about Catholic doctrine, traditions and history, then they should go to a Catholic web site.

Please be aware that Christianity Stack Exchange is not in the business of taking theological pot-shots at other denominations.  Each person is responsible for making up their own mind about what the Bible teaches and they are at liberty to check out various sources before drawing any conclusion.  If you have a complaint against Got Questions, you know what to do – send in your question and, who knows, it might even be assigned to me.  Wouldn’t that be fun!

Comment: Sorry if my comments sounded harsh, but the thing is, if non-Protestant readers don't _look_ for your mission statement they may believe what you write is universally accepted Christian theology regardless of church/denomination, e.g. "once saved, always saved" regardless of what else you do here on Earth. I tell you one can fall from grace by mortal sin, and there _is_ a purgatory. Another site, Creation.com, rejects the stance the age of Earth is 7,500 years (rather than 6,000) as well as the Shroud of Torino and (Neo-Tychonic) Geocentricity. These are independent of whether you believe...

Comment: ...in Protestant or Catholic theology. They're dismissed because they're probably too much _associated_ with Catholicism and Orthodoxy which is indicative of a general opposition to these churches.

Comment: Why do you call out baptism of infants? Several Protestant denominations practice [infant baptism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infant_baptism); it's not a Catholic-only, or even Catholic/Orthodox-only, doctrine.

Comment: @Matthew - I am perfectly aware that some Protestant denominations sprinkle infants with water and dedicate the child to the Lord, promising to bring it up in the Christian faith.  However, as a Protestant of the Reformed tradition, I subscribe to believer's baptism, and preferably by full water immersion, according to the example Jesus set.  This is also the view of Got Questions.  We are all entitled to our own opinions.

Comment: To be clear, you're saying that *all* of Got Questions (not just you, specifically) ascribes to a belief that is considered heretical by a significant number of *protestants*, including in particular Anglicans, Lutherans, Methodists and Presbyterians; at least some of which would also consider themselves "evangelical [and] theologically conservative"? Does GQ clearly state this anywhere? (FWIW, I *strongly* disagree with you on baptism, but this isn't the place to get into that.)

Comment: @Matthew - you are quite right, this isn't the place to get into infant baptism.  As for the suggestion that adult baptism is heretical, please read this Got Questions article to get a full and balanced biblical view on the subject of baptism: https://www.gotquestions.org/infant-baptism.html

Comment: You might add a link to [GotQuestions.org Statement of Faith](https://www.gotquestions.org/faith.html). It's something anyone using that site should refer to before asking a question. It's unfortunate that they don't put this information more up-front on their main page.

Comment: @RayButterworth  Excellent suggestion, Ray, for which I thank you.

Comment: @Lesley "because I have been a writer for them since 2012". Wow, that's great.  That explains how your answers usually have a polished "ready to published" feel to them.  Maybe some *GotQuestions* articles I referred to in my answers were written by you !  Keep up the good work.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple People from all over the world submit questions and receive a personal answer from a team of world-wide volunteer writers. Freely we have received and so freely we give, to point people to Christ Jesus, to the glory of God.

Answer (score 5):

From the [Got Questions](https://www.gotquestions.org/about.html) website mission statement we find the answer

> Got Questions Ministries seeks to glorify the Lord Jesus Christ by providing biblical, applicable, and timely answers to spiritually related questions through an internet presence."

> GotQuestions.org is a ministry of dedicated and trained servants who have a desire to assist others in their understanding of God, Scripture, salvation, and other spiritual topics. **We are Christian, Protestant, evangelical, theologically conservative, and non-denominational. We view ourselves as a para-church ministry, coming alongside the church to help people find answers to their spiritually related questions.**

> We will do our best to prayerfully and thoroughly research your question and answer it in a biblically based manner. It is not our purpose to make you agree with us, but rather to point you to what the Bible says concerning your question. You can be assured that your question will be answered by a trained and dedicated Christian who loves the Lord and desires to assist you in your walk with Him. Our writing staff includes pastors, youth pastors, missionaries, biblical counselors, Bible/Christian college students, seminary students, and lay students of God’s Word.

> All of our answers are reviewed for biblical and theological accuracy by our staff. Our CEO, S. Michael Houdmann, is ultimately accountable for our content, and therefore maintains an active role in the review process. He possesses a Bachelor’s degree in Biblical Studies from Calvary University, a Master’s degree in Christian Theology from Calvary Theological Seminary, and is currently pursuing a Master of Theology degree from Dallas Theological Seminary. Please go here for more information on our expertise.

[Creation ministries](https://www.gotquestions.org/about.html) states.

> Creation Ministries International is a group of non-profit ministries in several countries. Though each is a legally and financially autonomous body, we have formally unified our efforts as a federation of ministries under the banner ‘CMI-Worldwide’ that helps to ensure unity, harmony, and efficiency of outreach.
> Our role is to support the church in proclaiming the truth of the Bible and thus its Gospel message. We provide real-world answers to the most-asked questions in the vital area of creation/evolution, where the Bible is most under attack today—Genesis.
> **We are apolitical and non-denominational (as an organisation, not as individuals within it). We try to confine ourselves to matters as defined broadly by our Statement of Faith, and try to not get involved as a ministry in other controversies or issues within Christendom, no matter how important we, as individuals, might regard these.**

[Answers in Genesis](https://answersingenesis.org/about/)

is also reticent to denominationally identify but they declare that Trinitarianism  is a must for all to believe

> Church
> •   >The church of Jesus Christ is composed of all who are united with him in saving faith and who are thus members of the body of which he is the head (John 3:16, 3:36, 11:25; Acts 16:30–31; Romans 10:8–10; Ephesians 5:23; Colossians 1:18).
> •   Those who do not believe in Christ are subject to everlasting, conscious punishment in hell, but believers are secure to enjoy eternal life with God in heaven (Matthew 13:49–50, 25:46; John 3:16–18, 3:36, 5:24; 1 Thessalonians 1:8–10; 1 John 5:11–13; Revelation 21:8).
> •   **All Christians are to live in fellowship with a local, Bible-believing church (as portrayed in the New Testament), uniting in its worship of the triune God, supporting the great commission, and loving one another with pure and sincere hearts** (Acts 20:7; 1 Corinthians 11:17–33, 16:2; Hebrews 10:23–25, 13:17).

Comment: Yes but I'd like an example of which church/denomination one of their writers is a part from. It's clear to me they're cross-denominational but they're clearly Protestant, they are praising Martin Luther, they believe in "once saved, always saved" on Earth already, they believe the world is 6,000 years old (as per the Masoretic text) not 7,500 years (as per the Septuaginta) and they oppose the belief that the Shroud of Torino is Jesus' shroud and Geocentricity. They do so because of their anti-Catholic and anti-Orthodox stances, and since GotQuestions tries to teach people things that are...

Comment: ...incompatible with Catholic doctrine and many Christians would fall for their heresies I'm simply curious which denominations actually believe the things they believe. E.g. (most) Pentecostals _don't_ believe in "once saved, always saved" on Earth, hence it cannot be Pentecostals. GotQuestions also rather rejects deliverance (exorcism) as evident from thier post in an earlier question of mine, unlike many (charismatic) Evangelicals.

Comment: Some people declare all non catholic denominations of Christendom to be Protestant.

Comment: What? There are also Mormons and "Jehovah's witnesses" a.o. (if you consider them Christian).

Comment: As I said some lump them all under the umbrella of Protestant. See [the Merriam Webster dictionary definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/protestant)

Comment: Again, I know at least one writer/scientist for AIG is Seventh Day Adventist. We SDAs do not share the belief of burning in hell for eternity, also the Sabbath is worshipped by sda on saturday, we believe the earthly sanctuary is a copy of a heavenly one..so that scientist would hold some very different views from most others at AIG.

Comment: @adam what does it mean to worship the sabbath?

Comment: @User14 I'd find it easier to believe that the writers of the Merriam Webster are ignorant of the existence of non-Trinitarian churches than there being any substantial community of speakers who use the word "Protestant" to refer to LDS and JW. (Unless it's some weird US political label, like how "evangelical" has been co-opted in the USA.)